# How to check Authorization header in Alexa HTML Web API to prevent non Alexa device using HTML web app

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am making an HTML Web API skill, where I host my visual experience for my alexa skill on a website.
I would like to authorize the user on launch of the webpage. I notice there is this Authorization header you can put in your request https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/web-api-for-games/alexa-presentation-html-interface.html#request when you create this HTML Directive.

I have tried checking the authorization header using AWS WAF, since my site is hosted via Cloudfront. But there are tonnes of requests that come through so it gets very messy and can become expensive since I have to use LambdaEdge to check every request.

How can I check and process this Authorization header? So I can authorize whether the user has come from my Alexa skill?

Answer (score 0):

To determine if a request comes from your Alexa skill, you can include a static token from your web server in the `headers` object of the GET request used to request the HTML page. You would then receive this token value back, which can be used to ensure the request is coming from your skill.